# How to assert that database connection is in a transaction?

Tags: java, database, transactions, ibatis

I'm using an object/relational mapper to talk to the database. The library in my case is [iBatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/) which is also used for transaction management.
However, I recently had a case where iBatis didn't actually start a transaction even though `startTransaction()` etc. was called as [documented](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/user/com/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapTransactionManager.html#startTransaction%28%29).
After some debugging I found out that there was a configuration mistake on my side.

One might blame iBatis but I would like to avoid such misconceptions in the future.
So here's the question:

**How can I programmatically assert that the current database connection is running in a transaction?**

The databases I'm using are Oracle, MySQL and [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) (for testing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100%  sure if this is absolutely indicative of being in a tx, but [Connection.getAutoCommit()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getAutoCommit%28%29) tells you if the connection is in auto-commit mode, where auto-commit "on" means "no transaction".

There may well be cases where this assertion does not hold, but most JDBC-based frameworks will use that setting to control transactions.